# Error while using InputStreamReader with Java

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I tried to send an int value from the client to the server. This is the client code that I'm using below:

```
_port   = 8071;
_socket = new Socket("localhost", _port);

Random rand = new Random();
int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeInt(n);
dos.flush();
```

Server Code

```
try {
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    int ClientNumber= in.readInt();
    System.out.println(ClientNumber);
}
```

but I am getting an invalid stream header error.

> invalid stream header: 0000002B   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:781)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:278)     at
>   ServiceRequest.run(ServiceRequest.java:24)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Does anyone know what is causing the error?  Is my code setup improperly?

Comment: Why are you creating an `InputStreamReader, wrapping it in a `BufferedReader`, and then completely ignoring it?

Answer (score 1):

You're *writing* using a `DataOutputStream` and *reading* using an `ObjectInputStream`. You should be using [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) instead:

```
// Note declaration and assignment in a single statement. There's no point in
// making it null first.
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

// Note use of camelCase for variable name
int clientNumber = in.readInt();
```

You should also get rid of `input` here: you're not reading from it, and as this looks like it's a stream of *binary* data, it's inappropriate to treat it as text.

Oh, and you should be closing the input stream in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

try to change it like this

```
try {
             //   input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            int clientNumber= in.readInt();
            System.out.println(clientNumber);
}
```

it should work. ObjectInputStream can read only streams sent by ObjectOuputStream, it starts with a magic number (header) `0xACED`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html